# Finding suitable measure for optimal number of clusters for the specified clustering method and specified data

Tags: clustering

Suppose we have this kind of data and the preferred clusters (not in the case of the optimal number of clusters, but the shape of clusters) here:
[image]

I achieved the exact shape of clusters using KMeans! But I wonder which metric I should use to find the optimal number of clusters! I used *silhouette coefficient*, But it results in 2 clusters for these kinds of scattered data! So I'm slightly suspicious if I used a suitable metric for this problem.

To better explain this case, I want to dig into some details. One may ask what the `x ticks` and `y ticks` are.

- `x ticks` are the index of data! like `[1, 2, ... length of data]`
- `y ticks` shows the distance of each data point from a specific one.

So now it's a little bit clear what the idea is. I want data points within a distance range of (0, ) to be in the same cluster, and distance range of (, ) in the same cluster, and so on. But the problem is I don't trust the *silhouette coefficient* because it always shows me 2 clusters through all varieties of data that I have in this specific problem!

**Additional note:**
the shape of clusters should be like the example (this is intended), no matter how scattered the data is.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html#:~:text=If%20the%20line%20chart%20looks,fits%20best%20at%20that%20point](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20line%20chart%20looks,fits%20best%20at%20that%20point).
I would recommend approaching the problem using the elbow method with the metric set as distortion ( by default) to find the optimal number of clusters.